# How to use recursion to define a number series in maple

Tags: recursion, maple

I am new to maple and I want to define a number series as follows, but the error code is that there are too many levels of iterations. How to solve this problem?

g:=proc(x) g(x):=(sum(g(i),i=1..x-1))/(x!) end proc:
g(1):=0:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this:

```
g:=proc(x)
  option remember, system;
  local i;
  add(procname(i),i=1..x-1)/(x!);
end proc:

g(1):=1:

seq(g(n),n=1..6);

    1, 1/2, 1/4, 7/96, 35/2304, 847/331776
```

Inside the procedure, I could have written the recursive call as `g(i)`, but then its functionlity is tied to the name to which you assign it. By using `procname(i)` you are free to assign the procedure to another name.

For a Maple procedure, having `option remember` is a kind of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This speeds up this recursive procedure.

Having `option system` means that the stored results will get automatically cleared when Maple performs a garbage-collection cleanup. You could remove that, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But according to your code, the error is still ''too many levels of recursion''. Is there something wrong?

Comment: The code I showed runs fine, and without emitting an error message, if I cut&paste it in as either 1D plaintext Maple notation code or as (default in GUI) 2D Input.